# Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.4 Slow and Freezes

Tags: 18.04, freeze

I am fairly new to the linux operating system.

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04.4 onto a brand new samsung evo 860 SSD through a bootable image drive. I've had no lag on that bootable drive.

My computer has been extremely laggy and it's been freezing 5 minutes into startup every reset and I'm unsure why.

I have already updated and upgraded through the terminal. The image I downloaded was straight from the ubuntu web page. This is my second installation.

My computer specs are

Threadripper 1920x CPU

4 8GB vengeance lpx RAM

Asus ROG STRIX 2080 TI GPU

1TB samsung evo 860 SSD